# c# wpf when convert image to avi video using SharpAvi, video rotated

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I am converting image to avi video, but the generated video shows a rotated image.

Original image:

[image: Original Image]

Image from video generated:

[image: Image from video generated]

Following is portion of code I am using

```
var croppedImage = GetCroppedImageVideo(vidSize);
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp;
bmp = BitmapFromSource(croppedImage);
byte[] byteArray = BitmapToByteArray(bmp);
stream.WriteFrame(true, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

```
 public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapFromSource(CroppedBitmap bmp)
 {
     System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap;
     using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
         enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
         enc.Save(outStream);
         bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
     }
     return bitmap;
 }
```

```
public static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapData bmpdata = null;

    try
    {
        bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        int numbytes = bmpdata.Stride * bitmap.Height;
        byte[] bytedata = new byte[numbytes];
        IntPtr ptr = bmpdata.Scan0;

        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytedata, 0, numbytes);
        
        return bytedata;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bmpdata != null)
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpdata);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, bitmap data is stored upside-down.  The first scanline in the data is the bottom scanline of the image.  You'll need to make BitmapToByteArray() smarter, copying one scanline at a time.

Comment: Hans Passant, Could you please help me how I can copy one scanline at a time,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rotateflip?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant for your quick help. Issue is resolved